# Asp.net Web Site Administration tool icon is not showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I created an asp.net project in MVC3 on VS2012. It has AccountController and all other View folders. But i dont see Administrative tool icon on Solution explorer to create an admin. How can i get to this or enable the icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone has same problem and they dont see the icon for ASP.NET configuration. You can click on Projects -> ASP.NET configuration. It will open up same site where you can setup admin users.